# Variables and Django URLConf

Tags: python, regex, django, urlconf

I'm having trouble extracting a string from my URL. Here's what I've got.. it keeps 404ing.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', profile,),
)
```

views.py:

```
  def profile(request, username):
            ... 
      return ...
```

See anything obvious? Need more? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's the string you're giving it in the URL?

Comment: domain/accounts/user/foobar (this urls.py is in /accounts/)

Comment: Are you appending a slash at the end?

Comment: I can pass it either way, it still 404s.

Comment: Ah ha. The problem wasn't here. It was up above in my main urlconf where I had a terminating $. Thanks for your brainpower fellas.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing IN the view that raises a 404? And is the urls module correctly included in your main urlconf?

Comment: is there an __init__.py in /accounts/

Comment: This mystery has been solved.. please see my comment three up. Thanks for the continued ideas though!

Answer (score 0):

I usually a `/?$` at end of url pattern.

It is a common mistake and some browser add or not a trailing '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported your views module at the top of your URL file?

```
from views import profile

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', profile), 
    # also removed trailing comma after profile
)

# alternative

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', 'views.profile'), 
)
```

Have you got DEBUG = True in your settings file? That'll help find errors with a stacktrace that you should show us.